# Flex/actionscript snapshot

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
         var bmd:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(someSprite);
         trace("bmd size "+getSize(bmd));
         var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height);
     var snapshot:ImageSnapshot = new ImageSnapshot(0,0,bmd.getPixels(bounds));

         //var snapshot:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(someSprite);
     var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
     file.save(snapshot.data,'abc.png');
```

In the above code after saving the file, when
I try to open it, I get "This is not a valid bitmap file". I have tried 2-3 different viewers.

Comment: a similar question with a useful answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160353/flex-actionscript-snapshot-with-clipping-rectangle-and-scaling-matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend Amarghosh's answer, look to the constructor of ImageSnapshot

```
ImageSnapshot(width:int, height:int, data:ByteArray, contentType:String)
```

The `data` field isn't expecting BitmapData pixel data (`bmp.getPixels`), it's expecting data encoded in the given `contentType`.  So you could do:

```
var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
var bytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bmp);
new ImageSnapshot(width, height, bytes, encoder.contentType);
```

Once you have to encode it yourself anyway, you should probably do away with the second `ImageSnapshot` reference and use:

```
new FileReference().save(bytes, "abc.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

The [constructor of the ImageSnapshot](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/graphics/ImageSnapshot.html#ImageSnapshot%28%29) method takes width and height as its first two arguments. You are passing zeros. Change those to their actual values.

```
var snapshot:ImageSnapshot = new ImageSnapshot(bmd.width, bmd.height, 
        bmd.getPixels(bounds));
```

Comment: It looks like this wasn't the original problem (since they tried ImageSnapshot.captureImage first), but it certainly will stop them now.

Comment: @Michael, ImageSnapshot.captureImage is working fine. I used captureBitmapData since I wanted to later use a clipping rectangle and a scaling matrix.

Comment: @dta The fourth parameter to the constructor is the encoder, and it is `null` by default. Try passing `PNGEncoder`.

Comment: @amar fourth parameter is contentType(Flex SDK 3.5), which I tried passing as "image/png". Same effect.